# Should I replace an apricot tree that was mowed down to ground level?

Tags: trees, apricots

My neighbor accidentally mowed down an apricot tree I had recently purchased from a nursery last year.  I didn't dig up the roots and it started sprouting up again.  It's still very small but my question is:  Will it still bear fruit or is it an exercise in futility?

Answer (score 1):

As [user22542](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/22255/user22542) stated in the [comments on the question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/43349/chopped-apricot-tree#comment61191_43349):

> If the tree was from a nursery, it was a grafted tree grafted onto root stock. The "root stock" is typically about 4-6 inches above the ground where the graft is placed. If the tree was cut lower than four inches or so, your sprout is most likely coming from the root stock and probably won't grow into a satisfying tree. You probably want to replace it.

Comment: I know semi-dwarf and dwarf trees are often grafted onto rootstocks for the purpose of making them dwarf and semi-dwarf, but are standard-sized trees also almost exclusively grafted onto rootstocks? I know they might want to do it in some cases for disease resistance, temperature tolerance, etc., but I'm not really sure that this is common practice for standard trees, offhand.